# Why is voltage to ground as low as 47 volts on a 120 volt circuit?

Tags: electrical

I have a new garage with a 60 amp breaker running from the house to the garage. A new service panel with 240 volts; line 1 red, line 2 black. 240 VAC across terminals. 120 VAC from red to ground. 120 volts from black to ground.

I am trying to install 6 light fixtures in ceiling. But I can't even get two of them to light up completely. When I turn on the lights my amp reading is only 4 amps on a 15 amp circuit, which is good, but my voltage drops down to 47 VAC on that breaker to ground. It goes to 193 VAC on line 1 red to ground. So now I just discovered this weird voltage problem. My garage door has been working ok. But that breaking is dropping from 120 VAC to 75 VAC. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What are you calling ground?  Home wiring is not done from hot to ground, it is from hot to neutral.  It sounds like you don't have a neutral to the garage panel.

Answer (score 1):

There's either a problem with the grounded (neutral) conductor feeding the panel, or the one feeding the house. If you're only seeing the problem in the garage panel, and not the house. Then the problem is likely with the grounded (neutral) conductor feeding the garage panel.  Make sure the connections are tight, undamaged, and are not corroded. Also verify that the wire is not damaged, and is properly sized.

Depending on your level of experience, it might be time to contact a local licensed Electrician.

Comment: It almost sounds to me like he might be wiring his lights in series somehow but I can't really tell.

Comment: @Sam When the grounded (neutral) drops out, all the 120 volt loads basically end up wired in series on a 240 volt circuit.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, there are ways in incorrect measurement could make it show up as wired weird but they don't "end up in series". I just drew out the circuit diagram and your supposition doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Sam Then you drew the wrong diagram.  If the feeder neutral is dropped, devices connected to L1 and neutral, end up connected between L1 and L2 through devices connected between L2 and neutral.

Comment: @Sam Take a look at [this diagram](http://i.imgur.com/FjyeV13h.jpg). The upper diagram shows a normal 120/240V circuit.  The bottom diagram shows the circuit with a dropped neutral.  The yellow shows current flow.

Comment: think you for all of your answers. it was the neutral wire from the house to the garage. it did not get tightened down. when in installed a new grounding rod into the ground, at the garage. everything is working great now. except my typing and grammar, i am still woking on that. william doro